# Converting string to integer from form

Tags: php, type-conversion

Need a little help

I have

```
$_POST["zapremina"]=2000;
$_POST["starost"]="15%";
$_POST["namena"]="50%";
```

I want simple function to do this

```
$foo=(2000 - 15%) - 50%;
```

How to do that?

Comment: Is it `$_POST["zapremina"]="2000";
$_POST["starost"]='15%';
$_POST["namena"]="50%";` ?

Comment: To convert a string into a integer, you just have to `$a= (int) $b;`

Answer (score 1):

PHP is loosely typed, so you don't have to cast types explicity or do unnecessary operations (e.g. str_replace)

You can do the following:

```
$z = $_POST["zapremina"]; //$_POST["zapremina"]=2000;
$s = $_POST["starost"];   //$_POST["starost"]=15%;
$n = $_POST["namena"];    //$_POST["namena"]="50%;

$result = (($z - ($z *($s / 100))) - ($z * ($n / 100)));
```

Remember to use parentheses to have a readable code and meaningful var names.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$starostPercentage = (substr($POST["starost"], 0, -1) / 100);
$namenaPercentage = (substr($POST["namena"], 0, -1) / 100);

$foo = ($_POST["zapremina"] * (100 - $starostPercentage)) * $namenaPercentage;
```

This is what this does and why:

- Convert the percentages (like `15%`) from their text form to their decimal form (`substr(15%)` = `15`, `15 / 100` = `0.15`).
- Calculate `$foo` with these decimals. `2000 - 15%` is what you would write (as a human), but in PHP you need to write that as `2000 * (100 * 0.15)`, meaning: 85% of 2000).

Comment: You don't take `$_POST["zapremina"]` into account. Plus, it will result as : `(2000 * 15) -50`

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this:

```
  $zap = intval($_POST['zapremina']);
  $sta = intval($_POST['starost']);
  $nam = intval($_POST['namena']);
  $foo = ($zap * ((100-$sta)/100)) * ((100 - $nam)/100)
```

Answer (score 0):

add this function and then call it

```
function calculation($a, $b, $c)
    {
        $b = substr($b, 0, -1) / 100;
        $c = substr($c, 0, -1) / 100;
        return (($a * $b) * $c);
    }
```

and now you can call

```
$foo = calculation($_POST["zapremina"], $_POST["starost"], $_POST["namena"]);
```

go with function most of times, because it will be helpful for reusability.